# IOS BLE write characteristic Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a bluetooth device with bluetooth dual type, While reading data from device there is no problem, but when i am using CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse or CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse for writing values, it is not changing value on device.
For android its working fine with or without response characteristic type.

```
[peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
```

I have set notify to YES.
I am not sending data above 20 bytes.
Still same issue.

```
if ([command isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
                    NSData *cmdData = (NSData *)command;
                    command = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cmdData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                }
                command = [command stringByAppendingString:@"\r\n"];
                
                while ([command length] != 0) {
                    NSString* str = command;
                    
                    if ([command length] > 20) {
                        str = [command substringToIndex:20];
                    }
                    DebugLog(@"SENT:%@",str);
                    NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    [self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:self.selectedCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
                    
                    command = [command substringFromIndex:[str length]];
                }
```

I am using this method for debug.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
 {
   if (error) {
    DebugLog(@"didWriteValueForCharacteristic ERROR: %@",error);
}
else {
    DebugLog(@"didWriteValueForCharacteristic: %@",characteristic.UUID.UUIDString);
}
}
```

Getting this error while writing characteristics.

```
 error NSError * domain: @"CBATTErrorDomain" - code: 3 
 0x14db57d0 _userInfo __NSDictionaryI * 1 key/value pair 
 0x14d66550 [0] (null)
 @"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"Writing is not permitted." key 
 __NSCFConstantString * @"NSLocalizedDescription" 0x376b3cf4 value 
 __NSCFConstantString * @"Writing is not permitted." 0x37d109e4
```

Comment: Have you implemented the [`didWriteValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518823-peripheral?language=objc) delegate method?  Do you get an error with the write?

Comment: error NSError * domain: @"CBATTErrorDomain" - code: 3 0x14db57d0
_userInfo __NSDictionaryI * 1 key/value pair 0x14d66550
[0] (null) @"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"Writing is not permitted." 
key __NSCFConstantString * @"NSLocalizedDescription" 0x376b3cf4
value __NSCFConstantString * @"Writing is not permitted." 0x37d109e4

Comment: "@"Writing is not permitted." That seems explicit, no?

Comment: A device advertises for each characteristics if it can be read without response, read with response, written without response etc. Most likely your characteristics doesn't allow write with response. Android probably ignores it and converts it into a write without response while iOS generates an error. Use an app like "nRF Connect" to inspect the allowed operations of the characteristics.

Comment: i cross checked the service UUID, but its same for writing characteristics.

Comment: Could you read the properties of that characteristic (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristic/1519010-properties?language=objc) ? As Codo is saying, apparently, the device is saying it doesn't allow writing (which is in fact allowed), and since iOS read that, it doesn't allow the writing.

Comment: @Larme Device has to 2 properties Notify and Write without response.

Comment: Same Code is working with my other devices that is bluetooth 4.0 , but this new device is bluetooth 5.0. I dont know, but can this be a problem? I am using iphone 7 for development.I have tried different encoding also

Comment: I have checked on nrf connect and ble scanner app, commands are working with these 2 apps.Here what i am doing wrong?

Comment: "Device has to 2 properties Notify and Write without response": this is a strong indication that writing with response is not possible. Otherwise it would be listed.

Comment: Did you fix that?

Comment: I apologize for the delay in responding, the issue has been resolved, we had to write descriptor for the first time before writing characteristic to the device. This was due to the device's behavior.